# How to programmatically sort an autogenerated column in wpf datagridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I used an `List<T>` as source. The columns are auto generated. I can sort it in List. But I want to sort programmatically, Lets say 3rd column of data-grid view. How can I do it?

Comment: The information doesn't match; the DataGridView is a control in the older Windows Forms. The corresponding WPF control is simply a DataGrid. Which do you need info on?

Comment: My mistake sorry.. I want solution for DataGrid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically/19952233#19952233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a WPF DataGrid, check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/5d3942c8-e3e1-4284-b1b3-0b8b94150d86.

The Winforms DataGridView has two Sort methods, one which will specify a particular column, and another which will take an IComparer of DataGridViewRows. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort.aspx).