# Sort a wpf datagrid programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is there a way to sort a WPF DataGrid programmatically (for example, like if I clicked on my first column)?

Is there a way to simulate this click?

**Here is my code:**

```
Collection_Evenements = new ObservableCollection<Evenement>();
 
Collection_Evenements = myEvenement.GetEvenementsForCliCode(App.obj_myClient.m_strCode);
Collection_Evenements.CollectionChanged += Collection_Evenements_CollectionChanged;
myDataGridEvenements.ItemsSource = Collection_Evenements;
 
System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)myDataGridEvenements.ItemsSource;
dv.Sort = "strEvtType";
            
myDataGridEvenements.Focus();
myDataGridEvenements.SelectedIndex = 0;
myDataGridEvenements.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

I don't know why, but the line `dv.Sort = "strEvtType";` causes a strange thing, my Window shows up and the program doesn't continue to execute the next lines, nevertheless, I don't see the sort!

Comment: Can't you sort your DataGrid view? And refresh the layout?

Comment: have you an example please ? how doing this ? Thanks

Answer (score 51):

voo's solution was not working for me, `ItemsSource` was null, most likely because it was not directly set, but bound.
All other solutions I found here at StackOverflow were dealing with sorting the Model only, but the `DataGrid` header was not reflecting to the sort.

Here's a proper solution based on the incomplete script here: http://dotnetgui.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/how-to-properly-sort-on-wpf-datagrid.html

```
public static void SortDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid, int columnIndex = 0, ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
    var column = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex];

    // Clear current sort descriptions
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

    // Add the new sort description
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(column.SortMemberPath, sortDirection));

    // Apply sort
    foreach (var col in dataGrid.Columns)
    {
        col.SortDirection = null;
    }
    column.SortDirection = sortDirection;

    // Refresh items to display sort
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

In case of your code, it can be used like this:

```
SortDataGrid(myDataGridEvenements, 0, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Or by using the default parameter values, simply:

```
SortDataGrid(myDataGridEvenements);
```

Comment: Awesome method, easy to use and modify.  Thanks.

Comment: This does indeed show the soft arrow but that's it.  The sort is not actually performed.

Answer (score 7):

Get your ItemsSource's DataView and use its Sort property to specify the column you are sorting by:

```
(yourDataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView).Sort = "NAME_OF_COLUMN";
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. What's the name of the column, is the "header" property ? I don't found the name property :(

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni No, it is the name of the column of your source, that you bind to your DataGrid.

Comment: Ok, understood !Nevertheless when the programme go on the .Sort line, my programme window Show up and thats'all ! It's strange

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni What is the structure of your Evenement type? I suppose you should pass the property name of Evenement, which you want to sort by.

Comment: Setting the Sort value doesn't actually sort the data.

Answer (score 6):

[PerformSort](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,26406406cca70129) method of the DataGrid is what actually executed on a column's header click. However this method is internal. So if you really want to **simulate the click** you need to use reflection:

```
public static void SortColumn(DataGrid dataGrid, int columnIndex)
{
    var performSortMethod = typeof(DataGrid)
                            .GetMethod("PerformSort",
                                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    performSortMethod?.Invoke(dataGrid, new[] { dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex] });
}
```

Comment: Working like charm, ty :D

Comment: This is great!  You can also call the DefaultSort method if you for sure don't need to override the sorting.

Answer (score 5):

Fast & Easy way:

```
dgv.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
dgv.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ID", ListSortDirection.Descending));
dgv.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3):

This method works for me:

```cs
if (dgEvents.ItemsSource == null)
    dgEvents.ItemsSource = events.Entries;

CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgEvents.ItemsSource).Refresh();

dgEvents.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

dgEvents.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
    new SortDescription(dgEvents.Columns[0].SortMemberPath,
    ListSortDirection.Descending));
                
foreach (var col in dgEvents.Columns)
{
    col.SortDirection = null;
}

dgEvents.Columns[0].SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;

dgEvents.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) to filter, sort and group your items in a datagrid.

EDIT: add Sort, did not read the question carefully :)

```
 var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyData);
 view.Filter = ViewFilter;
 view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyPropertyToSort", ListSortDirection.Descending));


    private bool ViewFilter(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as MyObject;

        if (item == null)
            return false;

        //your filter logik goes here

        if(item.MyStringProp.StartsWith("Test"))
            return false;

        return true;


   }
```

Comment: if you dont bind to a object collection but to a datatable - you have to use IBindingListView.Filter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview_members(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To sort your DataGrid like if you clicked on your first column, you have to work on DataView created from WPF.
In this exampe the DataGrid is sorted every time that columns are AutoGenerated but you can select other event like DataGrid1_Loaded

```
using System.Windows.Data;

private void DataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource as DataView).Sort = DataGrid1.Columns[0].Header.ToString();
    }
```