# How to remember the sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

In a "Refresh" function for a WPF DataGrid, I'm trying to save the sorting criteria prior to the reload of items to the DataGrid, the new items loaded and then set the previous sorting criteria.  I'm using this code:

```
   void Refresh(DataGrid docsDataGrid) {
        var sd = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        DataGridColumn sortCol = null;
        foreach (var column in DocsDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (column.SortDirection != null)
            {
                sd = (ListSortDirection)column.SortDirection;
                sortCol = column;
            }
        }

        docsDataGrid.ItemsSource = GetLatestItems();
        sortCol.SortDirection = sd;
   }
```

With the code above, I do get the visual cue of "sorted column", but the newly loaded items are not really sorted, so it is a bit of a mirage.  I tried with `docsDataGrid.Items.Refresh()` after `sortCol.Direction = sd` but the datagrid does not pick up the sorting direction set programatically.

How can I leverage the built-in sorting facilities of the DataGrid and programatically set the column to be sorted (and actually sort rows by that column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research the SortDataGrid example in this SO Q&A helped me: [Sort a wpf datagrid programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically)

It seems that I should have dealt also with DataGridItems.SortDescriptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but why not save the selected SortDirection in a [setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)  and load it when you need it?