# Sort a column by clicking on a Button not on the ColumnHeader of a DataGrid c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with `HeadersVisibility="None"`.
I want to create a Button outside of the DataGrid that does exactly the same as if I clicked on the n column of the DataGrid(order the column).

I have tried the following code (`myDataGrid` is the name of my DataGrid):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     DataGridColumn column = myDataGrid.Columns[0];
     DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = GetColumnHeaderFromColumn(column);
     columnHeader.OnClick();
}
```

but the function DataGridColumnHeader.OnClick() is inaccessible due to its protection level.

I have also looked at the `class DataGrid` that is in `namespace System.Windows.Controls` where I have found this :

```
public event DataGridSortingEventHandler Sorting;

/// <summary>
/// Protected method which raises the sorting event and does default sort
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventArgs"></param>
protected virtual void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    eventArgs.Handled = false;
    if (Sorting != null)
    {
        Sorting(this, eventArgs);
    }

    if (!eventArgs.Handled)
    {
        DefaultSort(
                eventArgs.Column,
                /* clearExistinSortDescriptions */
                (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != ModifierKeys.Shift);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Method to perform sorting on datagrid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sortColumn"></param>
internal void PerformSort(DataGridColumn sortColumn)
{
    Debug.Assert(sortColumn != null, "column should not be null");

    if (!CanUserSortColumns || !sortColumn.CanUserSort)
    {
        return;
    }            
    if (CommitAnyEdit())
    {
        PrepareForSort(sortColumn);

        DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs = new DataGridSortingEventArgs(sortColumn);
        OnSorting(eventArgs);

        if (Items.NeedsRefresh)
        {
            try
            {
                Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invalidOperationException)
            {
                Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.DataGrid_ProbableInvalidSortDescription), invalidOperationException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I wasn't able to use that.
Any idea about how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with [SortDescriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions(v=vs.110).aspx) collection instead. This collection allows you to provide set of rules of how to sort items in the view.

You can find a good example on how to use it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952233/6597895

```
public static void SortDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid, int columnIndex = 0, ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending)
{
    var column = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex];

    // Clear current sort descriptions
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

    // Add the new sort description
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(column.SortMemberPath, sortDirection));

    // Apply sort
    foreach (var col in dataGrid.Columns)
    {
        col.SortDirection = null;
    }
    column.SortDirection = sortDirection;

    // Refresh items to display sort
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to apply sorting on 'dataView' and rebind it to dataGrid.

   ```
   private void SortButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      if(order == SORT_ORDER.ASC)
      {
        //Ascending   
        this.BindData(SORT_ORDER.DESC);
      }
      else
      {
        //Descending   
        this.BindData(SORT_ORDER.ASC);
      }
   }

   private void BindData(SORT_ORDER order)
   {
      //here read data from your datasource, by implementing that logic in 'GetDataSource()' function
       DataView dv = this.GetDataSource().DefaultView;

       if(order == SORT_ORDER.ASC)
       {
           dv.Sort = "Address ASC";
           this.SortLabel.Text = "Current sorting order is ascending";
       }
       else
       {
           dv.Sort = "Address DESC";
           this.SortLabel.Text = "Current sorting order is descending";
       }
       this.dgTest.DataSource = dv;
   }
   ```

Or

2. If you could use DataGridView it is much easier:

`this.myDataGrid.Sort(this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1, ListSortDirection.Descending);`