# WPF DataGrid: Disable sort for new item, but keep old item sorting programmatically

Tags: wpf, sorting, code-behind

I sort my DataGrid Columns programmatically, using solution from this forum thread [Sort a wpf datagrid programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically).

```
public static void SortDataGridByMultipleColumns(DataGrid dataGrid, Dictionary<int,ListSortDirection> sortInfo)
    {
         //here I force DataGrid to exit edit or add new mode
        RemoveNewAndEdit(dataGrid);

        // Clear current sort descriptions
        dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        //Apply sort
        foreach(var i in sortInfo)
        {
            var column = dataGrid.Columns[i.Key];
            dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(column.SortMemberPath, i.Value));
        }

        // Apply sort
        foreach (var col in dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            col.SortDirection = null;
        }
        foreach (var i in sortInfo)
        {
            var column = dataGrid.Columns[i.Key];
            column.SortDirection = i.Value;
        }
        // Refresh items to display sort
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

My problem starts when I add new row to DataGrid and press Enter - then new row is automatically sorted. When rows count is high, I can lost this row from my sight. So I need old rows sorted, column header style changed, but new rows not sorted (I want them be in end of list until some refresh happens).

I believe this can be achievable because when I sort columns in XAML with

```
SortMemberPath="columnPropertyPath" SortDirection="Ascending"
```

all works like I need, but I also need sorting from  code behind, because I hope to implement user sorting settings saving one day.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to present a huge number of records to a user in a datagrid. Users don't really want to scroll through an entire table. Maybe if you filtered your data then the issue would be obviated. Have you considered focussing the row just after the user adds it? I have a couple of behaviors intended to scroll into view and focus a given row based on the bound data.

Comment: I already implement some filtering options, and yes, this problem is not so bad when data is filtered. But when it is not, focusing last item does not do much, because you may have added 3 rows, auto sort throws them in different place of list, and if you want go back to first newly entered row you may have problem to remember it.

Comment: If you bound to a composite collection you could add new items to a separate collection than the old ones. Each can be a separate collectionview. You can sort collectionviews separately. I have no idea what happens when you edit a new row in a composite collection, I rarely allow users to edit let alone insert directly in a datagrid.

Comment: Hmm, did not know about composite collection, thanks for this tip, but this technique sounds kinda complicated. I rather would be glad if somebody could explain me difference between XAML and C# DataGrid sorting, because I think I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: You can programmatically make the same settings as the XAML. I work with bound data so I don't know if this'll work. Give it a go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically

Comment: I already used this thread for sorting as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You realise what you said in your question is "all works like I need" ?

Comment: All works like I need using XAML, but I need apply sorting in C# (code-behind, in xaml.cs).